# Seaborn white axes for black background presentation

Tags: matplotlib, seaborn

I need help with styling the axes of the graph given below. I need to enforce the axes as well as their labels to be white so as the png fits on a black background.

As a sample code I provide the standard:

```
# loading dataset 
data = sns.load_dataset("iris") 
  
# draw lineplot 
sns.lineplot(x="sepal_length", y="sepal_width", data=data)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
fig.savefig('MyImage.png', transparent=True)
```

which will provide [image]

So, essentially, I would like that the 4 axes and the labels become white.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a [dark style](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/style_sheets/dark_background.html):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.style.use('dark_background')
```

[image]